# Slow application if the number of Markers increases

Tags: osmdroid

On an OpenStreetMap map with osmDroid and osmBonusPack I display markers and by clicking on it a bubble opens, everything works as I want up to a certain number of markers.
The more markers I put on the map, the less responsive the application is.
For example with 1000 markers, it takes 6 seconds for the Toolbar menu to appear and as much for moving to another activity such as a simple text display.
My code.

```
private void creationMarker(GeoPoint arg,
                            String titre,
                            String proximite,
                            String description,
                            String identifiant) {
    double doubleProximite;
    Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
    startMarker.setPosition(arg);
    startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);

    InfoWindow infoWindow = new MyInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble_black, map);
    ((MyInfoWindow) infoWindow).setTitre(titre);
    ((MyInfoWindow) infoWindow).setDescription(description);
    ((MyInfoWindow) infoWindow).setSubDescription(identifiant);

    startMarker.setTitle(((MyInfoWindow) infoWindow).getTitre());
    startMarker.setTitle(((MyInfoWindow) infoWindow).getDescription());
    startMarker.setTitle(((MyInfoWindow) infoWindow).getSubDescription());
    startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.croix_verte, null).mutate());
    startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);

    doubleProximite = Double.parseDouble(proximite);
    Polygon circle = new Polygon();
    circle.setPoints(Polygon.pointsAsCircle(arg, doubleProximite));

    int myColorZone, myColorCloture;
    myColorZone = this.getResources().getColor(R.color.SurfaceZoneActive, getTheme());
    circle.setFillColor(myColorZone);     // couleur avec arrière plan transparent
    myColorCloture = this.getResources().getColor(R.color.ClotureActive, getTheme());
    circle.setStrokeColor(myColorCloture);// couleur de la circonférence    
    circle.setStrokeWidth(3);            // épaisseur du trait

    map.getOverlays().add(circle);
    map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

}
```

I use a loop with an SQL database for the marker data.

I guess the more markers there are, the more events the app has to handle.
What solutions could solve my problem.
Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: try turning off the polygon fill color

Comment: what version of osmdroid?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I am using osmDroid version 6.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month has passed, I have a solution, I studied the project https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack in the folder

https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/tree/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering
there are three files that interested me to manage clustering.

- MarkerClusterer.java
- RadiusMarkerClusterer.java
- StaticCluster.java

Thanks to M.Kergall and Roman Sidorov who are the creators of these java sources.

I simply copied these files into a test project. I was inspired by the methods that manage Markers in order to put circular Polygons, clustering side it works well, but depending on the zoom level, when the circular polygons are drawn there is no longer any interest in clustering. I countered this problem by managing the drawings of the polygons from the screen, I draw that what there is the screen, ditto for the Markers. Now with 20,000 Markers and Polygons it's just starting to hinder the responsiveness of the application, when before it was around 200. Here are some code snippets below.

Here are some code snippets below.
Main activity code

```
  private void getlireDataBaseMarkers() {

bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
bar.getLayoutParams().height = 6;
bar.requestLayout();

 Thread t = new Thread(){
 public void run() {

   Bundle messageBundle=new Bundle();

   nbrMarker = 0;
   dbMarkers = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
   if (dbMarkers.numberOfRows() == 0) {
        return;
    }

   SQLiteDatabase db = dbMarkers.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor res = db.rawQuery(SqlOrderVisibilite, null);
   res.moveToFirst();

   int qtyMarkers = dbMarkers.numberOfRows();
   bar.setMax(qtyMarkers);
   bar.setProgress(0);

   MyRadiusMarkerClusterer radiusMarkers = new MyRadiusMarkerClusterer(MainActivity.this);
   Double zoom = 15.0;
   radiusMarkers.setMaxPolygonZoomLevel(zoom);

   GeoPoint lePoint = new GeoPoint(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   while (!res.isAfterLast() &&
            !isPausing.get() &&
             isRunning.get()) {

        lePoint.setLatitude(res.getDouble(res.getColumnIndex(MARKERS_COLUMN_LATITUDE)));
        lePoint.setLongitude(res.getDouble(res.getColumnIndex(MARKERS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));

        Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
        startMarker.setPosition(lePoint);
        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person, null).mutate());

        Polygon circle = new Polygon(map);
        int myColorZone, myColorCloture;
        circle.setPoints(Polygon.pointsAsCircle(lePoint,getRandomDoubleBetweenRange(20,200)));
        myColorZone = MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent, getTheme());
        circle.setFillColor(myColorZone);
        myColorCloture = MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(colorPrimary, getTheme());
        circle.getOutlinePaint().setColor(myColorCloture);
        circle.getOutlinePaint().setStrokeWidth(4);

        radiusMarkers.add(startMarker);
        radiusMarkers.add(circle);
        nbrMarker++;

        myMessage = handler.obtainMessage();
        messageBundle.putInt(WRITE_QTY_MARKERS,2); // incrémenter le progress bar
        myMessage.setData(messageBundle);
        handler.sendMessage(myMessage);

        res.moveToNext();
     }
     map.getOverlays().add(radiusMarkers);
     res.close();
     dbMarkers.close();

     myMessage = handler.obtainMessage();
     messageBundle.putInt(WRITE_QTY_MARKERS,1); // afficher le nombre de markers
     myMessage.setData(messageBundle);
     handler.sendMessage(myMessage);

 }
 };
   isRunning.set(true);
   isPausing.set(false);
   t.start();

}
```

part of MyMarkerClusterers code

```
@Override
public void draw (Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,boolean shadow){
        //if zoom has changed and mapView is now stable, rebuild clusters:
        // si le zoom a changé et que mapView est maintenant stable, reconstruisez les groupes
        Double zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevelDouble();
        //if (zoomLevel != mLastZoomLevel && !mapView.isAnimating()) {
        if (!mapView.isAnimating()) {
            mClusters = clusterer(mapView);
            pClusters = pclusterer(mapView);
            renderer(mClusters, pClusters, canvas, mapView);
            setmLastZoomLevel(zoomLevel);
        }

        for (MyStaticCluster cluster : mClusters) {
            cluster.getMarker().draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        }

        for (MyStaticCluster cluster : pClusters) {
            if (getmLastZoomLevel() > mMaxPolygonZoomLevel) {
                cluster.getPolygon().draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            }
        }
    }
```

part of MyRadiusMarkerClusterer code

```
@Override
public ArrayList<MyStaticCluster> clusterer(MapView mapView) {

    ArrayList<MyStaticCluster> clusters = new ArrayList<>();
    convertRadiusToMeters(mapView);
    mClonedMarkers = new ArrayList<>(); //shallow copy
    ArrayList<Marker> mFiltreMarkers = new ArrayList<>(mItems);

    Iterator<Marker> it = mFiltreMarkers.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        Marker valeur = it.next();
        GeoPoint point = valeur.getPosition();
        // limiter le nombre de Marker suivant l'écran
        if( mapView.getProjection().getNorthEast().getLatitude()  >= point.getLatitude()  &&
            mapView.getProjection().getNorthEast().getLongitude() >= point.getLongitude() &&
            mapView.getProjection().getSouthWest().getLatitude()  <= point.getLatitude()  &&
            mapView.getProjection().getSouthWest().getLongitude() <= point.getLongitude()) {
            mClonedMarkers.add(valeur);
        }
        it.remove();
    }

    while (!mClonedMarkers.isEmpty()) {
        Marker m = mClonedMarkers.get(0);
        MyStaticCluster cluster = createCluster(m,null, mapView);
        clusters.add(cluster);
    }
    return clusters;
}

@Override public ArrayList<MyStaticCluster> pclusterer(MapView mapView) {
    ArrayList<MyStaticCluster> clusters = new ArrayList<>();
    convertRadiusToMeters(mapView);
    pClonedPolygon = new ArrayList<> (); //shallow copy
    ArrayList<Polygon> pFiltrePolygon = new ArrayList<>(pItems);
    Iterator<Polygon> it = pFiltrePolygon.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Polygon valeur = it.next();
            GeoPoint point = valeur.getInfoWindowLocation();
            // limiter le nombre de Polygon suivant l'écran
            if( mapView.getProjection().getNorthEast().getLatitude()  >= point.getLatitude()  &&
                mapView.getProjection().getNorthEast().getLongitude() >= point.getLongitude() &&
                mapView.getProjection().getSouthWest().getLatitude()  <= point.getLatitude()  &&
                mapView.getProjection().getSouthWest().getLongitude() <= point.getLongitude()) {
                pClonedPolygon.add(valeur);
            }
            it.remove();
        }

    while (!pClonedPolygon.isEmpty()) {
        Polygon p = pClonedPolygon.get(0);
        MyStaticCluster cluster = createCluster(null,p, mapView);
        clusters.add(cluster);
    }
    return clusters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Markers are quite heavyweight or at least they have been some time ago when I had similar performance issues as you have. There might be a potential to optimize them, but that would mean modifying the Osmdroid library and creating a pull request with such changes.

Try to do some profiling to make sure the problem is not in your code but in the library (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler.html).

Pay attention to how you read the data from the databse - don't do it on main thread and measure how long it takes to make sure it's not the main issue.

Try [SimpleFastPointOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Markers,-Lines-and-Polygons#user-content-fast-overlay) from Osmdrid - it is supposed to be optimized for higher numbers of Markers (they have to have the same icon, though). Even if its not flexible enough for your needs, try it out to verify Markers are the real problem. After that you can look at the source code and use it as a learning material to implement your own custom Overlay.

Comment: Hello
Thank you Josef for your response and the links that I will analyze at best.
It is true that I read the data in the main thread, I am aware of it but for the moment it does not bother me, it is more annoying once the markers are displayed, with the use of the menu of the Toobar lying around.
I will also look at this:

To mitigate performance issues with multipoint graphics, one strategy would be to reduce the number of points handed off to the map engine when at a higher zoom level (numerically lower), then increase the fidelity as the user zoom's in. 

I still have work

Comment: @PatBou The strategy you mentioned is usually called clustering and there's a support for that in osmbonuspack: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering/MarkerClusterer.java

Comment: I tried to group the markers, it did not improve the problem. I am creating another application as simple as possible with the same methods and the same way of programming, possibly improving to see if the problem persists. When I'm done, I'll share my comments with the code. I think it will take me a few days to get there. Thanks for your comments. see you soon.